# Reading Haskell Type

Tags: haskell

lets say I have:

```
t = \x y  -> x.y
```

its type is then:

```
*Main> :t t
t :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

If I understood correctly, `x.y` could be written as `x(y)`, which means we first solve `y` which is `(b -> c)` and then x which is `(b -> a)` and `a -> c` is just are parameters in function; We give `a` (x) and `c` (y). **Is this correct?** If not how do I read this? what does `(b -> c) -> (a-> b)` mean and which one is `x` which one `y`.

And how do I read this:

```
t1 = \x y z -> x.y.z 

*Main> :t t1
t1 :: (b1 -> c) -> (b2 -> b1) -> (a -> b2) -> a -> c
```

What is here `b1` what `b2` and how does this exactly work? Why is at the and just a ->  c when I have 3 parameters as input? Please help me understand this

Comment: You don't understand correctly.  `x . y` is not the same as `x(y)`.

Comment: `t = \x y  -> x.y ` is exactly the same as saying `t = .`. Have you tried looking up the definition of `.`. It has exactly the type signature GHCI is showing you here. It takes two functions: `x` of type `b -> c` and `y` of type `a -> b`, the names of the type variables are arbitrary but it is required that the two `b` are indeed equal, because the source of the first function needs to be the same type as the target of the second. And then `x . y` simply applies `x` to its input, then `y` to the result, which gives the overall type `a -> c`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond well, `t = (.)`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - oh I see, thanks, I forgot that the parentheses are required. Unfortunately SO doesn't let you edit comments after the first few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to write the function type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` would be `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)` where there are explicit parentheses around `(a -> c)`. This rewriting attempts to make it clear that the function does not take three arguments and return something of type `c`. It takes two arguments and returns a function of type `(a -> c)`. This is the concept of currying, and it is integral to Haskell programming<sup>1</sup>.

In your first example, `(b -> c)` is `x` and `(a -> b)` is `y`. The return type `(a -> c)` is the new function obtained by composing the parameter functions.

Your second example can be interpreted in the same way. `(b1 -> c)` corresponds to `x`, `(b2 -> b1)` to `y` and, `(a -> b2)` to `z`. The return type is obtained by first composing `z` and `y` to get a function of type `(a -> b1)` then composing this function with `a` to get a function of type `(a -> c)`. This function is what is ultimately returned.

---

<sub>1: In fact it is most correct to say that the function takes one argument of type `(b -> c)` and returns a function of type `(a -> b) -> (a -> c)` but, that's not particularly important.</sub>